# I posted a comment, but there is another user's name next to it

Tags: support, comments, comment-edits

On this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11343083/141022

I posted a comment:

> !important should generally be avoided in favour of using the natural
>   css cascade, a useful article

Oddly there is another user attributed as posting my comment, I thought at first that they must of simply edited it for the good of the community. However looking at the user's reputation https://stackoverflow.com/users/741749/liquid?tab=summary I wouldn't of thought that they have a high enough rep to do comment edits?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You posted the comment on *their* answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/11342903/59303 (10K users only). They then deleted their answer and posted your comment as their own on the other answer.

Comment: True, can't see anything malicious though, that member didn't want the useful comment to be lost. :)

Comment: Nice of them to pass the comment across, but be'd cool if there was some form of attribution, or perhaps even an semi automated way of tranferring comments.

Comment: @Alex Agreed; "Alex Key said..." would have been nice to add.

Answer (score 2):

The only users who can edit a comment are the user who posted it (when the comment is not older than 5 minutes), and moderators. When a moderator edits a comment, the username shown is still the username of who posted the comment.

For example, if I change [this comment](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/36072/cannot-delete-re-install-sharethis-module#comment36056_36072) on Drupal Answers, where I am moderator, the username is not changed.

[image: before]

[image: after]

If you see that the username shown for your comment changes, and you didn't change your username, then you are looking at another comment, which is a copy of your comment.